# Polling GPS Location on Android in Kotlin without Google api

Tags: android, kotlin, gps

I'm writing an android app in Kotlin and want to get the GPS location when ever a button is pressed.  How can I poll the current GPS location without using google.  I don't want constant updates since that would unnecessarily increase power consumption.

Comment: Using the gps chip in your Android device has nothing to do with google. You can use the gps without a wifi or mobile connection. I wonder what you have in mind.

Comment: What I mean is I don't want to use the Google api but rather the android.location.LocationManager directly

Comment: Well then do. You dud not clear up anything sadly.

Comment: I'm very new to both stackoverflow and Android development.  Would you kindly let me know what information I missed that would allow you to answer my question.  I'm hoping for a simple code example if possible.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to do a similar thing, get the one-time (not continuous) location without the need for an internet connection/API call.

I ended up doing the following:

```
 class YourActivity: Activity(){

   private var locationManager : LocationManager? = null
   private var locationListener: LocationListener? = null
    
 private fun setupLocation(){
    locationManager = context!!.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?

    locationListener = LocationListener { location ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Current Location -  ${location.latitude}:${location.longitude}")
        Toast.makeText(context, "Current Location -  ${location.latitude}:${location.longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() // This line is just to show you it is working, remove if not needed
        locationManager!!.removeUpdates(locationListener) // Use this line if you DON'T want constant updates, remove it if you DO want updates based on time and/or meters moved
    }
 }

 private fun getCurrentLocation(){
    try {
        // Request location updates
        locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListener)
        Log.d(TAG, "Location Request Successful")
    } catch(ex: SecurityException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Security Exception, no location available")
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out when I have the time, thanks!